# Change owner in child automatically

Tags: lookup, record-owner

When we change parent owner  in  lookup relationship, child owner should change. How can we achieve this in declarative manner?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to show us what you've tried and where you're stuck. Otherwise, you're asking us to do your work for you for free.

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple declarative flow solution in the images below. This is a record triggered flow on the parent object. The relationship from custom object 2 to custom object 1 is a lookup relationship as specified. In the scenario put out here all users have full access to both objects, in your scenario you may need to worry about permissions to the object and how to handle that. This also only updates the child owner when the parent's OwnerId changes, and doesn't enforce that the child maintain that OwnerId, to do this, you'll need to use an apex trigger or validation rule. Below is an example validation rule. This trigger also doesn't fire in the case that object2's lookup field changes. If you want that, you'll want to create a similar flow to the one pictured below that gets the parent record, and updates the Custom Object 2 record with the new parent's ownerId.

Please mark as correct answer if this helped you :)

```
IF(ISBLANK(Custom_Object_1__c), false, Custom_Object_1__r.OwnerId <> OwnerId)
```

[image: Flow Image]

[image: Flow configuration]

[image: Flow co2 variable]

[image: Flow co2List variable]

[image: Flow Get Records Image]

[image: Flow Loop Image]

[image: Flow Assignment Image]

[image: Flow Update Records Image]

Answer (score 0):

Good review, however, I suggest you try the Asynchronous Flow. As of Winter '22, they Added Asynchronous Path on Record-Triggered Flows

Additionally, look into the ISCHANGED() method on the flow trigger, so the flow ONLY runs if the Account Owner is changed for example.

== TL/DR ==

After creating a record-triggered flow, you can add an asynchronous path to execute the elements after the record operation that caused the trigger ends. Using this feature, flows can be more optimized and they can handle large data volumes.

[image: Optimize Flow for AFTER SAVE with Asyncronous Checkbox]

After marking the checkbox above, you can add the asynchronous path to the flow.

This can be used to make callouts or to avoid the “mixed DML” error. This is an error that you get if you try to update an object and a setup object (like a contact) in the same transaction.

[image: Flow Asynchronous Path is now available]

Just Trying to Help. Troy ~ Seattle